# Docker "waiting for an IP" when starting or creating new machine

Tags: virtualbox, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Been struggling to get this resolved for several days now.

Trying to implement a WSL and VirtualBox setup on Windows 10 Pro. The reasons aren't relevant to the issue, but using Hyper-V isn't an option. Trying to implement per:

https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/09/20/docker-on-wsl-with-virtualbox-and-docker-machine/

Whether I use [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) or just [`docker-machine`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases), the results are invariably the same. "Running as Administrator" just creates the VMs under the admin account which I don't want either. Tried `rm` and recreating the VMs a few dozen times.

Basically whether creating a new machine, or trying to start one, I get this error:

> (default) Waiting for an IP...
>
> Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

It still creates the machine but `state` is `timeout`:

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout
```

I do a `docker-machine env default` and get the following:

```
Error checking TLS connection: ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

The VM does show up in VirtualBox and has the same network adapter as my other working VMs (in that they can connect to the internet) with the exception of "Adapter 2". That is not on my other VMs:

[image]

The Docker VM has the following in terminal:

[image]
[image]

In addition, I have gone through the following suggestions and nothing has resolved the issue. The solutions generally involve recreating the VM.

Also, my host is at 192.168.1.x on the network.

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/457

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958619/docker-terminal-waiting-for-an-ip

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3268

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4053

**UPDATES:**

The `VBoxManager.exe` and the `docker-machine.exe` are in the same directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** "Waiting for an IP" is shown when `docker-machine` wants to connect the guest machine from host. Possible causes: host-only network is blocked in Firewall, DHCP disabled, wrong IPv4 configuration etc.

- Requirements:

  - Intel VT-x enabled in BIOS
  - Windows 10 64 bit with latest Ubuntu (or other GNU/Linux distribution) installed in WSL
  - [VirtualBox 64 bit](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) installed and Hyper-V disabled
  - [Docker Machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/) 64 bit for Windows (file name docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe)
  - Preliminary knowledge about networking and [docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)
- Environments:

  - VirualBox Guest (also Docker host): [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases) lightweight GNU/Linux image for Docker
  - VirtualBox Host: Windows 10 64 bit
  - Docker Client: `docker-ce` in Ubuntu WSL
  - Used IPv4 range in Host-Only interface: From 192.168.99.0 to 192.168.99.255 i.e. 192.168.99.0/24 with DHCP *enabled*. You may change this as you want but *DHCP is important for Docker Machine*

I followed the [article link](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/09/20/docker-on-wsl-with-virtualbox-and-docker-machine/) provided in the question. [Install `docker-ce` client](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) in Ubuntu WSL with these following commands:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
docker run hello-world
# you’ll get a message like this:
# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Now come back to Windows 10 host machine. Follow these step respectively:

- Download [Docker Machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/) 64 bit for Windows. Copy `docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe` file in VirtualBox installation folder or add `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH` environment variable so that docker machine executable can find `VBoxManage.exe`.
- Add Host-Only virtual interface from VirtualBox Manager window. Then set up all the required IPv4 configurations in that window or *from network control panel `ncpa.cpl`*. Any [private IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) can be used. Here are the screenshots:
- In Network Control Panel:

[image: ipv4-network-control-panel]

- In VirtualBox Manager Window:

[image: host-only-network-configuration]

- Allow `192.168.99.0/24` IPv4 range for both inbound and outbound connections in Windows Firewall. Also allow `VBoxHeadless.exe` in Windows Firewall for NTP connection in guest OS. Then run this command to create `docker-host` virtual OS in VitualBox with this command: `docker-machine.exe create docker-host`, it will install and configure VM guest OS.
- Run `docker-machine.exe env docker-host` command to show configured environments. Copy those environments in WSL world or copy in `.bash_profile` file as following (variables will change):

```bash
# These are example. Don't copy and paste.
export DOCKER_HOST=192.168.99.104:2376
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/mnt/c/users/username/.docker/machine/machines/docker-host
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=docker-host
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
```

In WSL Ubuntu try `docker run hello-world`. Use `docker-machine.exe stop docker-host` to stop the boot2docker VM. If Windows Firewall is blocking network connections then allow `VirtualBox.exe`, `VirtualBoxVM.exe` and `VBoxHeadless.exe` in Windows Firewall outbound rules. Also allow the host-only network IPv4 addresses with these following commands:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Host_Only_Network" -Name "Host_Only_Network_In" -Direction Inbound -RemoteAddress 192.168.99.0/24 -Action Allow
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Host_Only_Network" -Name "Host_Only_Network_Out" -Direction Outbound -RemoteAddress 192.168.99.0/24 -Action Allow
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87607/discussion-between-biswapriyo-and-sockpuppet).